# How do I get catpower?

Tags: kittens-game

In the wiki, it only says:

> Catpower is used in a variety of activities. Early on it is used to send out your hunters to bring back rare resources. As the game progresses, catpower becomes useful for many other tasks, such as trading.

This doesn't explain how can I produce catpower, and as I advance in the game I just see my catpower stays at 4.26, and I don't know how to increase it.

Edit: I have edited the wiki with the info in the accepted answer:

> Catpower is used in a variety of activities. Early on it is used to send out your hunters to bring back rare resources. As the game progresses, catpower becomes useful for many other tasks, such as trading.
>
> Catpower is produced by assigning kittens to hunter job.

Comment: Very good you edited the wiki! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must assign the `hunter` job to a kitten in the village tab. That will produce 0.060 catpower per tick. This is the only source of catpower ingame right now.

Comment: Thanks! I have missed it because I didn't assign the hunter job because I didn't have enough catpower to send the hunters.

Comment: That also explains why you had catpower in the first place! I couldn't remember any other source, but somehow you had some power, what is just weird if you never used the hunter job.

Comment: You can buy upgrades to get more power per kitten

Comment: @Mathias711 yeah, it was my mistake, I think I first assigned a hunter and then unassigned him as I couldn't send him. Anyway, now it is solved. Thanks!! I've updated the wiki with this info.

Comment: This is not the only source. Zebras give Catpower on IW.

Comment: It is the only source of catpower in the normal game. Indeed, with IW, you have zebras. But then you don't have hunters

Answer (score 2):

If you are going kittenless (for hardcore mode) then the game will provide zebras that are equivalent to hunters. They will disappear when you buy your first house.